# Can I add an action listener to a JLabel?

Tags: java, swing

I want to replace a JButton by a JLabel and I want my code to perform some action when the JLabel is clicked.

When I had the JButton I used action listener to handle clicks on the button:

```
myButton.addActionListener(new clicksListener(arg1,this))
```

When I replaced `myButton` by `myLabel` I got the following error message in the Eclipse:

> The method
>   addActionListener(ChipsListener) is
>   undefined for the type JLabel

But I do know that it should be possible to attach a click handler to the JLabel. Does anybody know how it can be done?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

**Add a `MouseListener` to the `JLabel`.**

Because `JLabel` is a `Component`, you can add `MouseListener`s to it.  Use that interface and write the `mouseClicked` event on your `MouseListener` to handle the click.

Comment: I don't get your logic here. Do you mean all `Component` can add `MouseListener` (any references)? And what kind of widget can add `ActionListener`?

Comment: Yes, the `addMouseListener()` method is defined on `Component`.  This class that generates `MouseEvent` objects when a mouse enters or exits the component, or when a button is pressed within the component or released after being pressed within the component.  Any class which extends `Component` can have any number of `MouseListener` references listening for these events.  `addActionListener()` is defined on `AbstractButton` and generates `ActionEvent` objects when the button is pressed.  Since `JLabel` doesn't extend `AbstractButton`, it does not generate `ActionEvent` objects.  Try `JButton`.

Answer (score 13):

An easier approach is to just use a JButton since it already supports this functionality by using an ActionListener.

You can make the JButton look like a JLabel by using:

```
button.setBorderPainted( false );
```

This approach is for when you want to handle a mouseClick, since an ActionEvent is guaranteed to be generated, whereas as mouseClicked event when using a MouseListener may not be generated in all situations, which can confuse the user.

Comment: I am afraid it's more complicated, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3025320/draw-a-jbutton-to-look-like-a-jlabel-or-at-least-without-the-button-edge

Comment: What are the situations in which the mouseClicked event won't be generated?

Comment: @Buffalo, A mouseClicked event is generated when a mousePressed and mouseReleased event are generated at the same point. So if the user move the mouse by a pixel between these two events you don't get the mouseClicked.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! isn't this the default implementation for a plethora of applications? besides, you could do your magic in the MouseListener's mousePressed implementation if you really wanted to overcome this.

Answer (score 12):

```
/*add a mouselistener instead and listen to mouse clicks*/
    jlable.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                    System.out.println("Yay you clicked me");
                }

            });
```

Comment: Always try to provide some explanation beyond just posting code. Meanwhile it could be obviously trivial for your, it might difficult for other people to understand.

Answer (score 3):

Sure. JLabels have a method which allow you to attach a MouseListener object. The MouseListener object requires a MouseAdapter() object. MouseAdapter is an abstract class which ideally serves as an Adapter for for creating on the fly listeners to do things.

```
JLabel label = new JLabel("<An image icon, if you'd like>");

// now lets attach a listener to your JLabel
lb.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() 
{
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) 
    {
        // THIS CODE WILL RUN WHEN THE EVENT OF CLICKING IS RECEIVED.
        // example of something you could do below.
        new Random().ints().limit(60).forEach(System.out::println);
    }
});
```