# Synthetica JButton Margins

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, boxlayout, synthetica

So, I have a Calendar solution for my employers where I am using a custom look and feel (Synthetica) and each cell in the table holds a `JPanel` with a list of buttons and a `PAGE_AXIS` `BoxLayout`. I am trying to reduce the gaps between each button so that they abut each other, and I've tried setting the borders to null except that destroys the button appearance. I have used the following (as recommended by Oracle to view the actual size of the components) code;

```
setBorder(BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(
    BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.red), 
    getBorder()));
```

And this is what I get;

[image]

Setting the margin does not work with whatever border version the buttons are using. So, is there any way to find the current border that it's using? So that I can set that border's insets manually, or something like that. Basically, I need the buttons to abut each other. Any ideas?

Clarification: I want the button's themselves to stay the same size, but I want the white space around them (highlighted inside of the red borders) to be gone,

Comment: I think that's not a problem with the button, but with the Box Layout itself. Have you tried another LayoutManager?

Comment: @GabrielCâmara - The red lines around the buttons mark the furthest point out of the JButton components, so the components are actually right next to each other but have extra space around the outside within the component. So it's not the layout that is the issue. At least I presume not anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several possibilities should be considered:

- Manipulate the button's bound properties: `setBorderPainted(false)`, *et al.*, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3026065/230513).
- See if a suitable `sizeVariant` is available, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14599176/230513).
- Use a custom UI delegate based on `BasicButtonUI`, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14599176/230513) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5755124/230513).

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. I tried the top two suggestions and got nothing (the space between them still isn't reduced). Looking into the last point now, but I'm having a little trouble understanding.

Comment: In any approach, you can override [`getPreferredSize()`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/230513), but beware of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12532237/230513).

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Realized I never accepted an answer on this one. I used a custom UI as in your last suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to get the Synthetica L&F to have a look but seems as though you have to create an account which I did not want to do. Anyways, a quick look around the website and I found a page which indicates how you can see and configure some of the values set in the L&F. Might be worth having a look there.

http://www.jyloo.com/synthetica/customize/